# Listing properties of power-point charts and objects in excel

Tags: excel, powerpoint, vba

I need some help here. So I have a power-point presentation with ~ 20 slides and each slide contains about 3-4 charts. Now, I need to jolt down the following in an excel sheet (using VBA macros):
 For each slide
 For each object
 1) Slide Name/Number
 2) Chart Name
 3) Chart type
 4) Chart height
 5) Chart width
 7) Chart - Position - Left
 7) Chart - Position - Top

Please help :)

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started on your way.  i will represent the slide number.  You just need to write the variables to your excel sheet.

```
For i = 1 to ActivePresentation.Slides(.Slides.Count).SlideNumber
   For Each s In ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes
   Dim x, y, Z, a, b, C, D, e As String
    Let x =s.Name
    Let y = s.Type
    Let Z = s.Id
    Let a = s.OLEFormat.ProgID
    Let b = s.Height
    Let c = s.Width
    Let D = s.Left
    Let e = s.Top
Next s
Next i
```